# QGIS automate creating equally long routes from a line street layer

Tags: qgis, pgrouting, routing

I have the task of designing routes within a street line layer that have similar lenght and are designed to drive along each road once.  This is for purpose of conducting a survey where each street needs to be filmed. Is there a QGIS addon that can do this?

[image]

Comment: You can search for the Chinese postman problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_postman_problem

Comment: Thank you Xeppit and BERA for responding.  Firstly, to answer BERA, yes the streets have a unique attribute.

Secondly Xeppit, I read your link, it's very interesting.  I have tried to install the Chinese Postman Solver however it seems not compatible with my version of python. I get error  :  ImportError: cannot import name 'gcd' from 'fractions' (/usr/lib/python3.10/fractions.py)